# Read Key Vault value in policy with Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to read value saved in Key Vault, or Key Vaulted value in Named Values?

Managed Identities have been enabled in APIM, and Secrete is created in Key Vault.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Error:" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://xxx" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>read it from Key Vault, or KeyValted value in Named Values</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

The links below seem relevant, but I wonder if there is simpler code, like a one line of code that used for Azure Functions.

https://madeofstrings.com/2019/06/13/azure-api-management-key-vault-and-managed-identities/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity

Comment: Whatever mentioned in the links are the best possible options. Setting PIM as managed identity and access key vault api.

Comment: Initially, I was looking for a simplier solution. I need to verify if it works and mark the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can not use the same way to get Azure key vault secret with Azure function. We need to use MSI to get access token then use key vault api to get the secret with the token. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity) and the [link](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/README.md)

1. Configure MSI

[image]

2.Set access policy in Azure Key Vault

```
  Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "your valut name" -ResourceGroupName "your group name" -ObjectId "the principal id you copy" -PermissionsToSecrets get, list, set, delete
```

3. Configure policy

```html
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="responseObj" timeout="30" ignore-error="true">
           <set-url>https://YOUR_KV_HOST/secrets/SEC_NAME/SEC_ID?api-version=7.0</set-url>
           <set-method>GET</set-method>
           <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://vault.azure.net" />
</send-request>
//with this process done , response obj will be setted into context . 

<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Error:" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://xxx" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>@((string)((IResponse)context.Variables["responseObj"]).Body.As<JObject>()["value"])</audience>
//Get value from responeObj in context
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc</issuer>
            </issuers>
</validate-jwt>
```